# How to refresh iPad screen left side view in split screen?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ipad

I had an iPad view which is splited into two views so i need to refresh left side view on the success of api response from right side view. But left side view code is in objective c and right side view code in swift.So how i can refresh the left side view.
I ahve created the delegate in swift class

```
  @objc protocol RefreshDelegate {
       func RefreshAfterSuccess()
  }
  class UpgradeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

var delegate:RefreshDelegate?
}
```

Now when i am not able import this delegate in Objective-c class and cannot implement RefreshAfterSuccess method in my objective-c class.

Comment: You can use the delegate for exchanging data between controller & for interaction between swift and objective c, use the breaze headesr.

Comment: I was trying delegate using bridging header but not succeed.

Comment: then post that code which is not working. or the step where you have issue in making bridging header.

Comment: @pawan i have Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

So my understanding is that your right view is the swift one of type UpgradeViewController.

Then in your class definition for the left one that is in objective-c

1) First you have to declare that it is implementing this protocol in <> brackets in the header file (could also do in the implementation, but no need to hide it here), and also add the required method declaration

```
@interface LeftViewController : UIViewController <RefreshDelegate>

-(void)refreshAfterSucces;

@end
```

2) Then add the actual implementation of the method in the .m file

```
@implementation

-(void)refreshAfterSucces {
    // Do your refreshing stuff here
}

@end
```

3) DON'T FORGET to set your right view controller's .delegate property to point to the left view controller object as you're adding them.

Method 2:

If these are two UIViewController subclasses nested in a UISplitViewController, then then each of them should have a .splitViewController property pointing to the UISplitViewController containing them.
The UISplitViewController itself should have a property .viewControllers that is an array with all of its child view controllers so from the right VC you should be able to access the left one (if using objc)

```
self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0]
```

then call methods on it, etc

Comment: Yes these two view controllers are in UISplitViewController but when i am trying to get view controllers it's coming nil.My rightSide view controller is in swift and left view controller is objc.

Comment: I tried this  let temp = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[0]
but temp gets nil.

Comment: Are your Left/Right child view controllers nested DIRECTLY into the UISplitViewController, or first into UINavigationControllers and then the navigation VC into the split VC.
In older libraries it's possible that .splitViewController property only returns the controller that contains it, and in this case this would be the nav controller. So you can try going self.navigationController.splitViewController.viewControllers[0]