# Sending data to server in swift3 and firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

[image]I am trying to update the node data on firebase but when i am sending an array it crashes. And its gives an error

> Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at 0. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.

Here is my code:

```
  reference_user.child(user_uid).updateChildValues(["name": username, "phone": phoneNo, "url": imgUrl, "emergency": emerLocalArr], withCompletionBlock: {( error, ref) in

                if (error != nil) {
                    KRProgressHUD.showError(progressHUDStyle: nil, maskType: nil, font: nil, message: "Couldn't Update the node")
                } else {
                 print("success")

                }
            })
```

`emerLocalArr` is `NSMutableArray`.
Here is my struct

```
struct Emergency{
var emer_id: NSNumber
var emer_name: String
var emer_phoneNo: String

init(emergency: NSDictionary) {

    if emergency.object(forKey: "id") != nil {
        emer_id = emergency.object(forKey: "id") as! NSNumber
    }
    else{
        emer_id = 0
    }

    if emergency.object(forKey: "name") != nil {
        emer_name = emergency.object(forKey: "name") as! String
    }
    else{
        emer_name = ""
    }

    if emergency.object(forKey: "phoneNo") != nil{
        emer_phoneNo = emergency.object(forKey: "phoneNo") as! String
    }
    else{
        emer_phoneNo = ""
    }
}

func convertToDictionary() -> [String : Any] {
    let dic: [String: Any] = ["id":self.emer_id, "name":self.emer_name, "phoneNo":self.emer_phoneNo]
    return dic
}
}
```

Comment: Of what type is your values? The error suggest that they are not compatible with Firebase

Comment: the value in emerLocalArr is of model class 
struct Emergency{
    var emer_id: NSNumber
    var emer_name: String
    var emer_phoneNo: String
    
    init(emergency: NSDictionary) {
        
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array contains custom object of type `Emergency`, so first you need to make array of dictionary form it. So add one instance method in your struct that return dictionary object and then make array of dictionary form your array of custom objects. Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40989886/6433023) to convert array of `struct` object to array of `Dictionary`.

After that set that array to your Firebase.

```
let array = emerLocalArr.map { $0.convertToDictionary() }

reference_user.child(user_uid).updateChildValues(["name": username, "phone": phoneNo, "url": imgUrl, "emergency": array], withCompletionBlock: {( error, ref) in
```

Comment: It's giving error on this line 
let array = emerLocalArr.map { $0.convertToDictionary() }  Value of type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'convertToDictionary'. I already added the convertToDictionary method in struct class.

Comment: @RahulGupta You need to add method `convertToDictionary` in your struct check that answer that I have linked and in this function make dictionary from your struct properties.

Comment: Sir i have added my struct also.

Comment: @RahulGupta You have declare you array with type `[Any]` so try like this way. `let array = (emerLocalArr as! [Emergency]).map { $0.convertToDictionary() }
` or change the declaration of `emerLocalArr` with `[Emergency]` instead of `[Any]`.

Comment: Sir it worked but it has updated the node name also.I have added the image in that emergency has 2 recordes with 0 and 1 but before updating it was 1 & 2 so how i can stop this?

Comment: @RahulGupta You mean there is already two objects and you want to add that object with your new array when you update records?

Comment: Actually i need to update the emergency dictionary by adding a new record of contact, by deleting the any record from emergency or i can update the existing records value.

Comment: @RahulGupta If you are talking about the order that start with 1 then don't know how to do that.

Comment: @RahulGupta Welcome mate :)

Comment: Nirav Sir can u please help me in this issue?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884553/how-to-refresh-ipad-screen-left-side-view-in-split-screen/42891231#42891231

Comment: @RahulGupta Let me check, If I have solution I will post it